# Print a Message

Tags: message-coding

Is there a way to `Print` a message suitable for `Message`?  I want to recycle some messages (but `Print` them, so they don't get suppressed after X times and look like `Print` output).

E.g.

```
Test::message="This is test number `1`.";
Message[Test::message,1]
```

[image]

Desired functionality:

```
PrintMessage[Test::message,1]
(* This is test number 1. *)
```

The inserting parts between back ticks is what really had me confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `StringForm`:

```
PrintMessage[mess_, val__] := Print@StringForm[mess, val]
```

Or `StringTemplate`:

```
PrintMessage[mess_, val__] := Print@StringTemplate[mess][val]
```

Comment: Thanks, I was digging around in the docs but didn't stumble on either of these.